# Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'user_id' doesn't have a default value

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-6

Me podrían ayudar con lo siguiente por fa, tengo una tabla usuario y otra cliente. Es relación mucho a muchos por lo que hay una tercera tabla "client_user".

Me sale el siguiente error al realizar una inserción:

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error:
>   1364 Field 'user_id' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into
>   `client_users` (`client_id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (1,
>   2020-03-25 22:15:19, 2020-03-25 22:15:19)) in file
>   C:\laragon\www...\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php on
>   line 669

userController.php

```
public function store(Request $request) {

        $rules=[
            'username' => 'required|unique:users,username',
            'firstname' => 'required',
            'lastname'=> 'required',
            'phone'=> '',
            'email'=> 'required|unique:users,email',
            'password'=>'required',
            'url_photo'=> 'url',
            'status'=> '',
            'client_id'=> 'required'
         ];

         $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules);

          if ($validator->fails()) {
             return response()->json(['error'=>$validator->errors()]);
          } 
          else{

            $user = Users::create([
                'username' =>$request->username,
                'firstname' =>$request->firstname,
                'lastname'=>$request->lastname,
                'phone'=>$request->phone,
                'email'=>$request->email,
                'password'=> Hash::make($request->password),
                'url_photo'=>$request->url_photo,
                'status'=>$request->status
            ]);

            $user->client()->create([
                'client_id' =>$request->client_id
            ]);         

           return response()->json($user->id,200);
            }

    }
```

> users.php

```
    class Users extends Authenticatable
    {
        use HasApiTokens, Notifiable;
        protected $fillable = [
            'username','firstname','lastname','phone', 'email', 'password','url_photo','status'
        ];
        protected $hidden = [
            'password', 'remember_token',
        ];


        public function categories()
        {
               return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class); 
        }
        public function client()
        {
            return $this->belongsToMany(Client_User::class);
        }

    }
```

Client_user.php

```
class Client_User extends Model
{
    protected $table ='client_users';
    protected $primarykey = ['id',];
    protected $fillable = ['client_id', 'user_id'];
public function client()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Client::class);
}

public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

}

Muchas gracias,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primero deberías tener solo 2 modelos:

- Cliente.php
- Usuario.php

Cada uno de estos con sus relaciones definidas así:

Modelo Cliente:

```
class Cliente extends Model 
{
    protected $table = 'cliente';
    public function usuarios()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Usuario::class)->withTimestamps();
    }
}
```

Modelo Usuario:

```
class Usuario extends Model 
{
    protected $table = 'usuario';
    public function clientes()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Cliente::class)->withTimestamps();
    }
}
```

**Nota**

> Para que la fecha sea almacenada puedes hacer uso del método `withTimestamps()` en cada una de las relaciones.

Por cierto tratando de seguir las convenciones de Laravel:

- Tu tabla pivote debe mantener los nombres en orden alfabético en singular
- Como tus tablas relacionadas están en singular entonces debes declarar en cada modelo una propiedad que indique el nombre de las mismas

Ahora ya que existen esas 2 relaciones y que tengas valores registrados en ambas tablas, entonces puedes almacenar valores en la tabla: `cliente_user` de esta forma:

**Primer consulta**

Si por ejemplo deseas mostrar los usuarios relacionados a un cliente entonces alcanza con hacer esto:

```
$clienteId = Cliente::findOrFail($id);

$clienteId->usuarios;
```

Donde:

- Obtenemos el id del cliente a buscar
- Obtenemos la relación del cliente con `usuarios`

**SEGUNDA CONSULTA**

Si ahora por ejemplo al Cliente con el id 1 le queremos adjuntar o vincular con el usuario de id 2 entonces usamos el método `attach` de esta forma:

```
$clienteId = Cliente::findOrFail($id);

$clienteId->usuarios()->attach(2);
```

> Esta segunda consulta registrará esa información en tu tabla pivote almacenando como llaves foráneas las llaves primarias de las 2 tablas relacionadas

**REFERENCIAS**

- [Relaciones muchos a muchos](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many)

Comment: Lo hice de esa manera pero busca hacerme una inserción directa en la tabla Client:Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'name' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `clients` (`updated_at`, `created_at`) values (2020-03-25 22:46:53, 2020-03-25 22:46:53)) in file C:\laragon\www\\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php on line 669

La idea es insertar un usuario con el id de un cliente ya existente

Comment: Extactamente con el mismo procedimiento?

Comment: Si, hice lo que me indicaste